# How can I change the dimension of the x axis ? (using relplot)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

As you can see below, My x axis with the rounds is not confusing. I would like to change the dimensions of the axis (or the figure) but even with figplot, I can't change the scale.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.relpot(x=atp.Round, y =atp.WRank)
plt.show()
```

Have you any idea or solution ?

Thanks in advance and have a good day !

[image: Picture of the issue]

Comment: [`sns.replot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) has the parameters `height` and `aspect` that control the dimensions of each subplot it would generate. You can use those to set your width and height, where `width = aspect * height`

Comment: Please include your sample code that will allow us to reproduce the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @TomJohnson Is it ok now ? If it's not, I will edit my post again. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex Hello, thanks for your answer. It didn't work with width but I used height = 30 and it worked ! Thx for your help.

Comment: The parameters are `height` and `aspect`. You must calculate the width that you want as a proportion of the `height`. So for a square plot `height=6, aspect=1`, for a plot twice as wide `height=6, aspect=2`, for a tall plot `height=6, aspect=0.5`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Alex Oh I get it now. ! I used width as a paramater at the beginning so of course it didn't work.  Thanks a lot and have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

@Alex
The parameters are height and aspect. You must calculate the width that you want as a proportion of the height. So for a square plot height=6, aspect=1, for a plot twice as wide height=6, aspect=2, for a tall plot height=6, aspect=0.5. Does that make sense? – Alex 14 hours ago